# How to add up the numbers in a row and display them in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using C# and Microsoft Visual Studio. I'm able to display my array through this code:

```
    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[,] initialArray = new double[3, 4] { { 5, 1, 9, 3 }, { 7, 8, 6, 4 }, { 2, 4, 9, 5 } };
        string rowOfInts = "";
        string columnsAndRow = "";

        for (int r = 0; r < initialArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            string tempString = "";

            for (int c = 0; c < initialArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                rowOfInts = tempString + " " + initialArray[r, c];
                tempString = rowOfInts;
            }
            columnsAndRow = columnsAndRow + rowOfInts + "\n";
            lblDisplay.Text = Convert.ToString(columnsAndRow);
        }
        // displays Display = new displays(initialArray, rowOfInts, columnsAndRow);

        if (chkRowTotals.Checked == true)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < initialArray.GetLength(0); r++) 
            {
                int intTotal = 0; 
                string tempString = "";

                for (int c = 0; c <initialArray.GetLength(1); c++)
                {
                    rowOfInts = tempString + " " + initialArray[r, c];
                    tempString = rowOfInts;
                }
                columnsAndRow = columnsAndRow + rowOfInts; 
                intTotal += Convert.ToInt32(columnsAndRow);
                lblDisplay.Text = Convert.ToString(intTotal);
            }
        }
    }
```

but I don't know how to add the numbers by rows. Is there any way that I can total the numbers in my array by row and then display them in my label (lblDisplay)?

edit: I don't want the entire array added up- just the rows. So, the output would be 18, 25, and 20.

Comment: Throw an `int` outside of your loop, then add to it on each iteration.

Comment: @AlexGravely wouldn't that add all of the numbers in my array?

Comment: Ah. In that case, you have everything you need there, just two lines. In your inner loop, add each number in that row to `intTotal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things wrong in your code, to be completely honest. I will just put what I think is the solution you are looking for:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double[,] initialArray = new double[3, 4] { { 5, 1, 9, 3 }, { 7, 8, 6, 4 }, { 2, 4, 9, 5 } };
        string rowOfInts = "";
        string columnsAndRow = "";

        for (int r = 0; r < initialArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            string tempString = "";
            double inttotal = 0;

            for (int c = 0; c < initialArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                rowOfInts = tempString + " " + initialArray[r, c];
                tempString = rowOfInts;
                inttotal += initialArray[r, c];
            }
            columnsAndRow = columnsAndRow + rowOfInts + " row total of = " + inttotal.ToString() + "\n";

        }
        txtbx.Text = Convert.ToString(columnsAndRow);
    }
```

Comment: Upvoted; I should warn you that this is likely their homework =D. Not judging, just letting you know.

Answer (score 0):

Something to the effect of:

```
const int numRows = 3;
const int numColumns = 4;

double[,] initialArray = new double[numRows, numColumns] { { 5, 1, 9, 3 }, { 7, 8, 6, 4 }, { 2, 4, 9, 5 } };
double[] rowTotal = new double[numRows];

for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++)
    {
        rowTotal[i] += initialArray[i, j];
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Current row total: {0}", rowTotal[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var initialArray = new double[3, 4] { { 5, 1, 9, 3 }, { 7, 8, 6, 4 }, { 2, 4, 9, 5 } };
// List that will hold the sum of each row
List<double> rowSums = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < initialArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    // accumulator
    double rowSum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < initialArray.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        rowSum += initialArray[i, j];
    }
    // add the row sum to our list
    rowSums.Add(rowSum);
}

// will put "18, 25, 20" in your label's Text
lblDisplay.Text = string.Join(", ", rowSums);
```

You should consider using a [flattening your array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/flatten-array) as it has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Linq:

```
var numberOfRows = initialArray.GetLength(0);
var numberOfColumns = initialArray.GetLength(1);

var sumOfRows = Enumerable
    .Range(0, numberOfRows)
    .Select(r => Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfColumns).
        Aggregate(0d, (a, i) => a += initialArray[r, i]));

lblDisplay.Text = string.Join(", ", sumOfRows);
```

However, it might be a lot easier to use a Jagged array instead. The Linq expression would be a lot easier.